# Is "stabilize into" a valid collocation?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, collocation, to-into

Here is the full sentence:

"Despite the fluidity of this trope, in the middle of the twentieth century, it briefly stabilized into a distinct shape".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It sounds ok to me but  I'd use only one comma, after "century".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please visit the help center for guidance on how to post a question. Our sister site ell.stackexchange.com would probably be more appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a valid collocation, though "stabilize to/into" shows up in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stabilize%20into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstabilize%20into%3B%2Cc0) only fairly recently, from around 1920-1940. Here are some examples it turns up:

- If a specific, fixed bank angle is selected, then the airspeed is allowed to stabilize to the constant value corresponding to this constant bank angle.
  [- Stephen Corda, Introduction to Aerospace Engineering with a Flight Test Perspective](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=frfBDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA766&dq=%22stabilize%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB4vn1gtzhAhUNA3IKHRKYCCoQ6AEIKjAA)
- When meaning and action around an object stabilize into routine, especially when these arrangements are institutionally supported, objects can powerfully shape action.
  [- Terence E. McDonnell, Best Laid Plans](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=k2gpDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22stabilize%20into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKwdDAgtzhAhVYWysKHSH7BqgQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22stabilize%20into%22&f=false)
- They are all ongoing processes affected by many things that stabilize into particular patterns.
  [- Peter Coleman, The Five Percent](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=PRk4DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&dq=%22stabilize%20into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI26-AhNzhAhUZXn0KHUJbD2wQ6AEINjAC)

Comment: @Naffster You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Seems valid, if uncommon, to me.

List of examples of use of [stabilize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/stabilize) on online Cambridge dictionary has one use of "stabilize into". Phrase itself seems to try and draw parallel to collocations "coalesce into" ([list of examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/coalesce)) and "congeal into" ([list of examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/congeal)), which are common, while avoiding permanency of congealing and coalescing (emphasised by addition of "briefly").